# Could not install packages due to an OSError: No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras-2.7.0.dist-info/RECORD'

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to downgrade the version of Keras and whenever I try to install or uninstall it, I run into this error.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or
directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras-2.7.0.dist-info/RECORD'
```

I first tried `pip uninstall keras`, it gave the above error

I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435526/11115848, but it still gives the same error on installing again and moreover shows a prompt to install Keras.

Comment: this is probably not [on-topic for DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Apologies, where can I probably ask except from stackoverflow as I am not allowed to post a question there

Comment: yup temporary ban is the reason :/ and yeah that's why I posted here only hoping for an answer